# Is my approach correct?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I am struggling with the following problem:

Given a directed graph with 3<=N<=1000 vertices and 3<=M<=1000000 edges you can choose a simple cycle of this graph and walk it.While you are walking the cycle at each edge you are asked a question if you answer correctly your money is doubled else it's halved.

Let's say you have D dollars and the chance you answer correctly a question at an edge e_i is p_i, then the expected money to have after answering that question is :

2*D*p_i+1/2(D*(1-p_i))=D(1/2+3*p_i/2)

Find if there is a simple cycle in the given graph which you can walk and the expected money you will have after walking it is more that the money you started with.

My approach is to use Johnson's algorithm to find all simple cycles and then check if there is any cycle for which the expected money is more than the one you are starting with but I keep getting time-outs. Am I missing something ? Is there an observation I have to make or should I just try to optimize my code more?

Comment: I think this one is for [Math Overflow] (http://mathoverflow.com)

Comment: @T-Heron Yes and no :-) Some mathematical insight can help a lot, but without it this is an algorithmic question.

Comment: Is solution to find one cycle or to check if cycle exists?

Comment: It's possible to use the simple heuristic of considering only edges with p_i big enough the coefficient is >= 1. Any cycle consisting of such edges would have the property we are looking for. But I wonder, why would You get some time-outs? Is this a problem from some programming competition?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
 By the way it's from a greek programming training site that's why I am saying I am getting time-outs ,it's not from a running competition

Comment: @Ante just find if such cycle exists.

Answer (score 0):

The trick in this problem is to reduce this to negative cycle detection.

If you start with `x` amount of money from a vertex and go around a cycle `e_1,e_2,…e_k` and get back, you will end up with `x*f_1*f_2*…f_k` where `f_i=(1/2+3*p(e_i)/2)`. What you want is `f_1*f_2*…f_k > 1`. But this is the same as having `ln(f_1) + ln(f_2) … ln(f_k) > 0`.

So make a graph with edge weights as `-ln(f_k)`. The problem then reduces to negative cycle detection, which can be done using some algorithm like Bellman-Ford.